# Is it possible to 'turn off' indentation in asp.net controls?

Tags: asp.net, html

When I use built-in controls in asp.net I can see many tab characters added at start of each line of the generated html output. **Is it possible to 'turn of' these?** I'd like to get rid of this waste.

For example when I use `GridView` control, it generates `<table>` tag which looks like this:

```
<div>
        <table>
                <tr>
                        <th>...</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                        <td>...</td>
                </tr>
                ...
        </table>
</div>
```

But I want to see this:

```
<div>
<table>
<tr>
<th>...</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>...</td>
</tr>
...
</table>
</div>
```

I wonder who designed this silly stuff. Although it is "just a few bytes", it sends many unneeded waste over internet if you look at it from a long time period point of view. (I understand that indentation makes it more readable, but still at least those inner `<th>` and `<td>` tags are a bit too much indented.)

Or do you think I am completely wrong? [Are those tabs important for The World?]

Answer (score 2):

> I wonder who designed this silly stuff

[Microsoft Corporation](http://www.microsoft.com/).

> Or do you think I am completely wrong?

I think you are completely wrong. HTML is to be read and interpreted by browsers. You, as a developer, could use developer tools such as FireBug to inspect the actual DOM tree in a nice way. Humans/users don't give a s..t about how your HTML is indented. They look at the final product rendered by the browser and this is what you should be focusing on. Actually in production in order to optimize bandwidth you should compress your HTML and remove all white-spaces. Could be done with custom [response filters](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38067/Compress-Response-and-HTML-WhiteSpace-Remover).

Comment: So you say I am completely wrong when I want to generate html without unneeded spaces, and your argument is Firebug? I don't understand your logic.

Comment: @AlKepp, my argument is that if you want to inspect the DOM you use FireBug, you don't look at the HTML source in your browser. Personally I never look at the generated HTML output of an application. I never use it to debug problems with my code. I use developer tools. Like FireBug. All I need to know about the actual HTML is that it validates (http://validator.w3.org) and that it is as compact as possible in order to save bandwidth. I don't give a damn about whitespaces and indentation. Have you looked at the HTML source of one of the most visited sites on planet http://www.google.com?

Comment: My main question here is if that indentation can be turned off. (You argue like if you misinterpreted what I wrote. I don't need those tabs, I want my html files to be short.)

Comment: @AlKepp, yes it can. You could use a response filter which will remove all whitespaces from your HTML.

Comment: Its probably worth noting that IE 8 and up have their Dev tool bar built in. Chrome's Element Inspector was always built in.

Comment: @ConradFrix, I don't think it's worth mentioning IE as a developer browser at all, as it is not. Chrome's developer's tools are nice but not as good as FireBug. I mean there's nothing better for developers than FireBug currently. Nothing. Sorry you can't convince me. A web developer should absolutely use FireBug for any serious web development.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov ignoring the no true Scotsman stuff it really depends on where you are and what you need to do. If you've got full control of your dev environment awesome only use the tools you want to use. Not everyone is in that position at all times.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, when I write a page (I use the `Repeater` control, so there's a bit of a difference), I always indent my HTML. Yes, even the content within the `<th>` and `<td>` tags.

I can understand your point (especially when we talk about using gzipped and minified copies of JavaScript libraries) when you're talking about a production application that's never debugged. However, without HTML indentation, it would be incredibly difficult for me to unwind problems in my layout or errors I made when I wrote CSS or HTML properties.